# Rendering items via props after handling some processing using Vue.js and Vue CLI 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-cli

I have a main component called **`App.vue`** and a child one **`MyTable.vue`** which wraps a table of data and showing only the 10 first rows, i'm working with vue cli 3 and when i ran the `npm run serve` command and go to the given address, it renders only the **head** of my table, but when i add some code in the `mounted()` function inside `MyTable.vue` like `console.log()` it renders also the body of my table, the problem comes back when i refresh my page, how can i deal with that ?

**these is my components**

### *App.vue*

```
<template>
  <div class="main-page">     
    <my-table title="todos" :cols="todo_attr" :rows_data="todo_data"></my-table>        
 </div>
</template>
<script>

import MyTable from './components/MyTable.vue'
import todos from './assets/todos.json'
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data(){
return{
  todo_attr:[
    "todoId","id","title","completed"
  ],
     todo_data:[]   
}
  },
  components: {
    MyTable
  },
  mounted(){this.todo_data=todos;}
}
</script>
```

### *MyTable.vue*

```
<template>
<div class="vet-container">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th class="tab-head-cell" v-for="col in cols" :key="col">{{col}}</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="tab-rows_data-row" v-for="row in currentPageData" :key="row.id">
                <td class="tab-rows_data-cell" v-for="(cell,key,index)  in row" :key="key+index" > {{cell}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'my-table',
    props: {
        title: String,
        cols: {},
        rows_data: {}

    },
    data() {
        return {
            currentPageData: {}
        };
    },
    methods:{
        createFirstPage(){    
          this.currentPageData = this.rows_data.slice(0, 10);
        }
    }
    ,
    mounted() {
     this.createFirstPage();
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: the list of **todos** can be found via this link : [todos](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you declared `cols` and `rows_data` as objects in `MyTable.vue` but you declared them as arrays in `App.vue`. You also declared `currentPageData` as an object instead of an array. It may cause some errors.

Second, you should prefer do this:

```
<template>
  <div class="vet-container">
  <table>
    <thead>
    <th class="tab-head-cell" v-for="col in cols" :key="col">{{col}}</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="tab-rows_data-row" v-for="row in currentPageData" :key="row.id">
      <td
      class="tab-rows_data-cell"
      v-for="(cell,key,index)  in row"
      :key="key+index" >{{cell}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'my-table',
  props: {
    title: String,
    cols: Array,
    rows_data: Array,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      index: 0,
      size: 10,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    currentPageData() {
      const start = this.index * this.size;
      const end = start + this.size;
      return this.rows_data.slice(start, end);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

You could then pass index in `props` and change it on parent on click on buttons.

Little explanation of the `computed` property: this property act like calculated `data`. You can use it just like any other `data` or `props` and you can calculate its content based on other stuff, like here, with the current index and the size of page.

Comment: i think that the problem is inside the `mounted()` function or the cycle life of the component, the code inside this function would not be executed when i reload my page, but when i edit this function by adding some code and i save and when i check my page i find that the table body is rendered

Comment: Yes a part of the problem is in the `mounted` function, because `rows_data` are not yet instanciated when you try to slice it. I edited my answer to include a working example using the `computed` property. You should give it a try :)